# Retrieve a multiple stripe charges in php

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I just want to know if there is way to retrieve charges with multiples charges_id in stripe.

For example in the [docs](https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/retrieve?lang=php) show how to get one charge. But we need get multiple charges. So, we don't want to made a multiple calls to the stripe method retrieve, this is to slow. We dont want to make this:

```
foreach ($result as $p_key => $payment) {
     $charge = $this->CI->stripe_lib->retrieve_charge('ch_......', 'secret_key');
     if (isset($charge['charge'])) {
         $amount_charged = (float)$charge['charge']->amount / 100;

         // echo "<pre>";
         // print_r($amount_charged );
         // echo "</pre>";

     }
}
```

this is in Codeigniter. And this is the function on the library:

```
public function retrieve_charge($charge_id, $secret_key) {

    $errors = array();
    try {

        \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey($secret_key);
        $charge = \Stripe\Charge::retrieve($charge_id);
        return array('charge' => $charge);

    } catch(Stripe_CardError $e) {
        $errors = array('error' => false, 'message' => 'Card was declined.', 'e' => $e);
    } catch (Stripe_InvalidRequestError $e) {
        $errors = array('error' => false, 'message' => 'Invalid parameters were supplied to Stripe\'s API', 'e' => $e);
    } catch (Stripe_AuthenticationError $e) {
        $errors = array('error' => false, 'message' => 'Authentication with Stripe\'s API failed!', 'e' => $e);
    } catch (Stripe_ApiConnectionError $e) {
        $errors = array('error' => false, 'message' => 'Network communication with Stripe failed', 'e' => $e);
    } catch (Stripe_Error $e) {
        $errors = array('error' => false, 'message' => 'Stripe error. Something wrong just happened!', 'e' => $e);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        if (isset($e->jsonBody['error']['type']) && $e->jsonBody['error']['type'] == 'idempotency_error') {
            $errors = array('error' => false, 'message' => $e->getMessage(), 'e' => $e, 'type' => 'idempotency_error');
        } else {
            $errors = array('error' => false, 'message' => 'An error has occurred getting customer info.', 'e' => $e);
        }
    }

    return $errors;
}
```

With this code: \Stripe\Charge::all(["limit" => 3]); returns all charge but in the docs I didn't see if this method returns me also a multiple charges id.

I appreciate all your help.

Thanks and I'm sorry for my english.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your question. It seems you have already identified the right method to retrieve multiple charges using the PHP library!

You are correct in that `\Stripe\Charge::all(["limit" => 3])` call [0] will return you multiple charges, up to the limit specified in the arguments [1].

In the response to the above request, you will receive an array of charge objects [2], each having an `id` field [3] that would be the charge ID.

Hope that helps! Please let me know if you have any questions.

Cheers,

Heath

[0] https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/list?lang=php

[1] https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/list?lang=php#list_charges-limit

[2] https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/object?lang=php

[3] https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/object?lang=php#charge_object-id

Comment: thanks a lot @hmunoz for your answer, but this would involve making one call to get all charges (may be hundreds or thousands). That we want is get the details of certains charges, for example: ch_1, ch_2, ch_3, ch_50, ch_80, ch_83, etc, whiout loop through all charges.

Comment: Hi @Anibal,
Unfortunately, there isn't a way currently to retrieve charges by specifying an array of all charge_ids you want to look up.

What I would recommend is that you list all charges with the `Charge::all()` function above and narrowing in on the charges you are interested in by specifying a certain date range or a specific customer (complete list of supported parameters [0]).

Once you have this array of charges, you can then look it up for the charge_ids you are want details on. 

[0] https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/list?lang=php

Comment: One thing to note is that `Charge:All()` will only return a maximum of 100 charges [0] per call. You would have to use autopagination [1] or cursor based pagination using the `ending_before` or `starting_after` parameters [2] to fetch more charges after the first 100.

[0] https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/list?lang=php#list_charges-limit
[1] https://stripe.com/docs/api/pagination/auto?lang=php
[2] https://stripe.com/docs/api/pagination?lang=php

Comment: Hi @hmunoz thanks a lot for your answer. I appreciate all info that you gave me. I think I need to evaluate this situation and work with this limitation